# JS Tetris deleting line issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, tetris

am learning JavaScript and for this I wanted to make a Tetris game.
Till now I got a lot of functionality, but am stuck at the clearRow() (clear line) issue.

My code works as follows. I check every row of the gameBoardSquared 2D array. If all the blocks in a row have a blue color, this line should be deleted.

Here is my code:

```
function clearRow(){

for(var rows = 0; rows < gameBoardSquared.length; rows++){
    var isFullLine = false;
    if(gameBoardSquared.every(k => k[rows].squareColor == "blue")){
        isFullLine = true;
        console.log("fds");
    }
    if(isFullLine){
        //here I would like to iterate trough all the elements, that are true in the upper if statement (if(gameBoardSquared.every...)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

but it is not this.
I would really appreciate, if I could insert the .splice into the if(arr.every()) condition, but not to only delete one tetromino.

edit:
I am iterating trough columns since the whole gameboard is made in a canvas. There the axis are reverted.

Comment: looks like you are confusing rows and cells. `gameBoardSquared.every(k ` and `for(var rows = 0; rows < gameBoardSquared.length; rows++){` seems to be iterating through rows when it should be columns

Comment: Oh, I know now, what you mean. I wanted to iterate again trough rows to catch all of the filled ones and to delete them. It's just something that is left by me when trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Thanks SO for the motivation :-).

```
function clearRow(){
    for(var rows = 0; rows < gameBoardSquared.length; rows++){
        while(gameBoardSquared.every(k => k[rows].squareColor == "blue")){
            for(var i = 0; i < gameBoardSquared.length; i++){
                console.log(gameBoardSquared[i].splice(rows, 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```